How to summarize NMDS results into single points with error bars?
I have conducted an NMDS analysis and plotted the results. However, for the left plot, I would like to obtain a plot where the points from my various treatments are "summarized" into a single point with error bars, instead of what I have gotten.
I provide images to better explain what I want plus my code just in case. The left plot in the "desired outcome image" was slapped together in paint, but I have seen these sort of plots in the literature (e.g.: Wild et al., 2014: "Input of easily available organic C and N stimulates microbial decomposition of soil organic matter in arctic permafrost soil"). Also they can be made with R (as stated in the paper), but I just cannot figure out how or find a tutorial/thread.
TLDR: Instead of left plot in "my own results" I want left plot in "desired outcome".
Anyone out there who can provide me with an answer?


Data:
structure(list(Treatment = c("cs", "cs", "cs", "cs", "ce", "ce", 
"ce", "ce", "1e", "1e", "1e", "1e", "4e", "4e", "4e", "4e"), 
    `i15:0` = c(0.038194995, 0.070483554, 0.066509405, 0.02656837, 
    0.024501448, 0.123952048, 0.158812766, 0.048075503, 0.042707725, 
    0.173164856, 0.180104263, 0.162216335, 0.115837661, 0.321511027, 
    0.071114723, 0.194906795), `a15:0` = c(0.044211789, 0.068811108, 
    0.073337229, 0.027031903, 0.022587532, 0.110265989, 0.160241456, 
    0.04339058, 0.049255133, 0.170517668, 0.199264385, 0.154776239, 
    0.155124629, 0.307943496, 0.108737048, 0.194099006), `i16:0` = c(0.01782632, 
    0.031463009, 0.026320789, 0.014625177, 0.022190061, 0.051997237, 
    0.046475526, 0.021942647, 0.051267309, 0.093449378, 0.069918965, 
    0.079624038, 0.06122343, 0.146494324, 0.052256874, 0.087334431
    ), `16:1ω7c` = c(0.039181929, 0.064326029, 0.086634185, 
    0.038006212, 0.022568139, 0.111887339, 0.165744837, 0.067105897, 
    0.137095761, 0.251219335, 0.289299471, 0.276622201, 0.27988588, 
    0.359676703, 0.139182249, 0.422137325), `16:1ω7t` = c(0.006220504, 
    0.010372077, 0.011011986, 0.004331443, 0.004117218, 0, 0.016843949, 
    0.006185401, 0.01803384, 0.028295985, 0.02584535, 0.022196905, 
    0.031798788, 0.035570765, 0.018700339, 0.029134652), `16:1ω5c` = c(0.006957877, 
    0.013528688, 0.01707799, 0.00905064, 0.004203058, 0, 0.027683594, 
    0.019134836, 0.025887336, 0.057077469, 0.044940654, 0.075541206, 
    0.044327836, 0.07670695, 0.030417356, 0.127591822), `16:0` = c(0.161037157, 
    0.217587364, 0.183307479, 0.111910577, 0.120445222, 0.283660219, 
    0.333206677, 0.159581943, 0.381897382, 0.546141255, 0.379301617, 
    0.495703963, 0.595253076, 0.82653097, 0.315155249, 0.661990203
    ), `10Me 16:0` = c(0.008269657, 0.014867341, 0.013705167, 
    0.012176098, 0.00835949, 0, 0.024733271, 0.017993387, 0.035947535, 
    0.045106349, 0.042875244, 0.065672086, 0.045513819, 0.06571743, 
    0.032058128, 0.066599308), `i17:0` = c(0.019685743, 0.03821051, 
    0.027937903, 0.019666127, 0.020166071, 0.046030564, 0.039561999, 
    0.026039132, 0.065939957, 0.098216633, 0.05983684, 0.09703123, 
    0.07018488, 0.147983747, 0.052353567, 0.088069882), `a17:0` = c(0.015062966, 
    0.022975609, 0.019264877, 0.011306938, 0.021646964, 0, 0.031982809, 
    0.015408173, 0.063935976, 0.073056821, 0.05054158, 0.05557835, 
    0.052089068, 0.10369428, 0.043037189, 0.052491098), `17:1ω7c` = c(0.00428813, 
    0.005924667, 0.006807987, 0.003405714, 0.003100204, 0, 0.013317004, 
    0.00564397, 0.016137123, 0.025780419, 0.023742601, 0.023814462, 
    0.019288199, 0.028512027, 0.014184457, 0.028922394), `cy17:0` = c(0.007978745, 
    0.020837575, 0.01825151, 0.011241851, 0.00562496, 0.037428369, 
    0.037580648, 0.017905727, 0.048752828, 0.083793406, 0.074501831, 
    0.07364191, 0.063787883, 0.117775824, 0.018038811, 0.111461244
    ), `17:0` = c(0.019832995, 0.012288693, 0.016991794, 0.008906124, 
    0.015236496, 0.015629559, 0.033730574, 0.0123141, 0.047954072, 
    0.028504626, 0.036356188, 0.035751034, 0.057116806, 0.042311441, 
    0.030330047, 0.040258649), `10Me 17:0` = c(0.001967074, 0.005045711, 
    0.00419998, 0.004370348, 0.003049929, 0.008151985, 0.007665705, 
    0.005935455, 0.015951364, 0.016685053, 0.014753528, 0.026085769, 
    0.016103559, 0.024073947, 0.010236068, 0.027865828), `18:2ω6c` = c(0.006594482, 
    0.007138977, 0.011574679, 0.004210641, 0.005679057, 0.027457586, 
    0.017027548, 0.009400472, 0.030160413, 0.065461815, 0.0287921, 
    0.029084061, 0.03284687, 0.050610582, 0.022530081, 0.037026116
    ), `18:1ω7c` = c(0.063524628, 0.088011652, 0.064329236, 
    0.064397171, 0.054856424, 0.166204663, 0.135438015, 0.115515402, 
    0.243383684, 0.376587956, 0.191241645, 0.440923087, 0.268201012, 
    0.425619782, 0.157976459, 0.439641379), `18:1ω7t` = c(0.004339952, 
    0.009364455, 0.005604494, 0.003420479, 0.004732609, 0, 0.007931135, 
    0.004397696, 0.026273248, 0.022871272, 0.012048718, 0.009896217, 
    0.017956939, 0.024215907, 0.010083998, 0.009818137), `18:0` = c(0.152940658, 
    0.073439855, 0.092698797, 0.057528911, 0.122326908, 0.067357563, 
    0.206714901, 0.078515138, 0.316168351, 0.134563875, 0.195944637, 
    0.23662163, 0.496532244, 0.195335661, 0.195507236, 0.224913003
    ), `10Me 18:0` = c(0.003363204, 0.010884316, 0.00630025, 
    0.007155183, 0.004602433, 0, 0.009008464, 0.007156422, 0.017567226, 
    0.027625515, 0.014018314, 0.025328229, 0.014619648, 0.038015042, 
    0.019599232, 0.025250972), `cy19:0` = c(0.002473057, 0.012073369, 
    0.00509506, 0.005664806, 0.002999546, 0.002440478, 0.007511822, 
    0.008154366, 0.020524718, 0.043994752, 0.013101494, 0.02818864, 
    0.016691308, 0.049769211, 0.005023214, 0.02574527), `20:0` = c(0.129819646, 
    0.055626381, 0.08380711, 0.053866344, 0.134982677, 0.047650998, 
    0.13721842, 0.082087929, 0.196526612, 0.067974935, 0.135653207, 
    0.126493615, 0.296495625, 0.095695561, 0.153097109, 0.11146806
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))

Data workaround (wa):
structure(list(Treatment = c("cs", "cs", "cs", "cs", "ce", "ce", 
"ce", "ce", "1e", "1e", "1e", "1e", "4e", "4e", "4e", "4e", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -37L
))

My R-code:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggvegan)
library(ggpubr)
#Load data and workaround for legend
data <- read.csv2("comSFdata.csv", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
wa <- read.csv2("wa.csv", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
#Create new dataframe w/o 1. row
com = data[,2:ncol(data)]
#Turn data from dataframe to matrix format
mcom = as.matrix(com)
#Run NMDS - set.seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)
nmds1 <- metaMDS(mcom, distance = "bray", k = 2, maxit = 999,  trymin = 500, trymax = 500)
#Prepare data for plotting
fort <- fortify(nmds1)
#Add workaround for custom legend
fort['Treatment'] <- wa['Treatment']

#Generate 2 plots:
p1 <- ggplot() +
#Customizes samples; alpha = opaqueness
  geom_point(data = subset(fort, score == 'sites'),
             mapping = aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2, colour = Treatment),
             alpha = 1) +
#Code axis range and force rendering of objects "outside" the range
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.365, 0.365), xlim = c(-1.05, 1.05), clip = 'off') +
#Remove legend
  theme(legend.position="none") +
#Add custom legend
  annotate("text", x = 1.1, y = 0.38, size = 4, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "#C77CFF",
           label = ("Control start")) +
  annotate("text", x = 1.1, y = 0.355, size = 4, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "#00BFC4",
           label = ("Control end")) +
  annotate("text", x = 1.1, y = 0.33, size = 4, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "#F8766D",
           label = ("1% substrate addition")) +
  annotate("text", x = 1.1, y = 0.305, size = 4, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "#7CAE00",
           label = ("4% substrate addition")) +
#Generates coordinate system axis at the origin
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 0, linetype = "dashed", linewidth = 0.8, colour = "gray") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0), linetype = "dashed", linewidth = 0.8, colour = "gray") +
#Removes grids & background & adds a frame
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = "NA", linewidth = 1, linetype = "solid")) +
#Add title below grid customization so it is in the foreground
  annotate("text", x = -1.1, y = 0.375, size = 5.5, fontface = "bold", hjust = 0, colour = "black",
           label = ("(a) Slump Floor (SF)")) +
  #Customize left plot axis
  theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(-3, "mm"),
        axis.ticks = element_line(linewidth = 1.05),
        axis.text.y.right = element_blank())

p2 <- ggplot() +
#Add custom x-axis label
  geom_point(data = subset(fort, score == 'species'),
             mapping = aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2), alpha = 0) +
#Code axis range and force rendering of objects "outside" the range
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.365, 0.365), xlim = c(-1.05, 1.05), clip = 'off') +
  geom_segment(data = subset(fort, score == 'species'),
#Adds & customizes vectors for PLFAs
               mapping = aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = NMDS1, yend = NMDS2),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0, "npc"),
                             type = "closed"),
               colour = "black", size = 0.8, alpha = 1)+
#Enable custom label colours and set to bold text
  geom_text(data = subset(fort, score == 'species'),
            mapping = aes(label = label, colour = label, x = NMDS1 * 1.1, y = NMDS2 * 1.1),
            alpha = 1, size = 3, fontface = "bold") +
#Remove legend
  theme(legend.position="none") +
#Add custom legend
  annotate("text", x = 1.1, y = 0.38, size = 4, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "black",
           label = ("Non-specific")) +
  annotate("text", x = 1.1, y = 0.355, size = 4, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "#ff0000",
           label = ("Gram-positive bacteria")) +
  annotate("text", x = 1.1, y = 0.33, size = 4, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "#ff8800",
           label = ("Gram-negative bacteria")) +
  annotate("text", x = 1.1, y = 0.305, size = 4, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "#00b300",
           label = ("Fungi")) +
#Customize label colours
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("i15:0" = "#ff0000", "a15:0" = "#ff0000", "i16:0" = "#ff0000", "16:1ω7c" = "#ff8800", "16:1ω7t" = "#ff8800", "16:1ω5c" = "#ff8800", "16:0" = "black", "10Me 16:0" = "#ff0000", "i17:0" = "#ff0000", "a17:0" = "#ff0000", "17:1ω7c" = "#ff8800", "cy17:0" = "#ff8800", "17:0" = "black", "10Me 17:0" = "#ff0000", "18:2ω6c" = "#00b300", "18:1ω7c" = "#ff8800",  "18:1ω7t" = "#ff8800", "18:0" = "black", "10Me 18:0" = "#ff0000",  "cy19:0" = "#ff8800", "20:0" = "black")) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 0, linetype = "dashed", linewidth = 0.8, colour = "gray") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0), linetype = "dashed", linewidth = 0.8, colour = "gray") +
#Removes grids & background & adds a frame
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = "NA", linewidth = 1, linetype = "solid")) +
#Add title below grid customization so it is in the foreground
  annotate("text", x = -1.1, y = 0.375, size = 5.5, fontface = "bold", hjust = 0, colour = "black",
           label = ("(b) Slump Floor (SF)")) +
#Customize right plot axis
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(-3, "mm"),
        axis.ticks = element_line(linewidth = 1.05))

#Generate multi-panel plot with 2 columns & add/customize labels
ggarrange(p1, p2, widths = c(2.2, 2), ncol = 2, nrow = 1)```


Is this close to what you need?

The code:
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

# Make some fake NMDS results:
sampsize <- 10
treatments <- c("start", "end", "1%", "4%")
treatment <- rep(treatments, each = sampsize)
nmds1means <- c(-0.3, 0, 0.3, 0.6)
nmds2means <- c(0.2, -0.7, -0.1, -0.4)
nmds1 <- sapply(nmds1means, FUN = function(x){rnorm(n = sampsize, mean = x, sd = 0.12)}) %>% as.vector
nmds2<- sapply(nmds2means, FUN = function(x){rnorm(n = sampsize, mean = x, sd = 0.2)}) %>% as.vector

df <- data.frame(treatment, nmds1, nmds2)

# Plot as "normal" NMDS plot:
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = nmds1, y = nmds2)) +
  geom_point()

# Prepare data for summarised NMDS plot:
df2 <- df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(treatment) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(nmds1_mean = mean(nmds1),
                   nmds1_se = sd(nmds1),
                   nmds2_mean = mean(nmds2),
                   nmds2_se = sd(nmds2))

# Plot summarised NMDS plot:
ggplot(data = df2, mapping = aes(x = nmds1_mean, y = nmds2_mean, shape = treatment)) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 16, 17, 18)) +
  geom_errorbar(mapping = aes(ymin = nmds2_mean - nmds2_se, ymax = nmds2_mean + nmds2_se)) +
  geom_errorbar(mapping = aes(xmin = nmds1_mean - nmds1_se, xmax = nmds1_mean + nmds1_se)) +
  lims(x = c(-1, 1), y = c(-1, 1)) +
  xlab("NMDS1") +
  ylab("NMDS2")


This is quite nice. I think it is best to use + coord_fixed() for the correct aspect ratio. The suggestion uses lims to the same effect, but it requires more care to have it always correct. Moreover, both the original question and the answer ignore correlation (covariance): the bars should not be parallel to the axes, but they should be the principal axes of covariance ellipse.  See ordibar in vegan how this should look like in conventional graphics.

You helped a lot, thank you very much. I now understand how to summarize the data and how to plot it. However I don't know how to extract nmds means from my nmds analysis and calculate the SD for my various treatments. Sry if my questions seem stupid, I have just 1 week of R experience.
@Jario: The example I gave seems to be the standard in my field. As I understand it, the diagram is just for visualization and an analysis of similarity is conducted to test for significant differences between treatments and/or locations. Hence, covariance gets ignored. But feel free to correct me.

@AndréFaust The practice may be standard in your field, but it is wrong. NMDS solution can be rotated (axes can be tilted) and the solution is still the same.  If you take into account covariances, the error bars are unchanged (they rotate with axis rotation), but error bars calculated along axes will change.

I found a solution thanks mainly to @Teodor (and a bit of ChatGPT). My code is quite similar but still somewhat different. Also, there is a lot of customization concerning my plots following the solution. As I oriented myself very closely to a graph from a scientific publication, I decided to post it in case someone wants the code for a (hopefully) publication-worthy looking plot (Fig. 1).
I also attached the code for a simple version of the same graph but using ordibar to generate error bars that take covariance into account as proposed by @JariOksanen (Fig. 2).
Teodor's approach:
library(vegan)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggvegan)
library(ggrepel)
library(ggpubr)
#Load data
data <- read.csv2("comSFdata.csv", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
#Create new dataframe w/o 1. column
com = data[,2:ncol(data)]
#Turn data from dataframe to matrix format
mcom = as.matrix(com)
#Run NMDS - set.seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)
nmds1 <- metaMDS(mcom, distance = "bray", k = 2, trymax = 10000)

#Prepare data for, and calculate means + se --> Summarize into single points
nmds_coords <- as.data.frame(scores(nmds1, display = "sites"))
nmds_coords['Treatment'] <- data['Treatment']
nmds_summary <- nmds_coords %>%
  group_by(Treatment) %>%
  summarise(
    NMDS1_mean = mean(NMDS1),
    NMDS2_mean = mean(NMDS2),
    NMDS1_sd = sd(NMDS1),
    NMDS2_sd = sd(NMDS2),
    NMDS1_se = NMDS1_sd / sqrt(n()),
    NMDS2_se = NMDS2_sd / sqrt(n()))

#Prepare data for 2. plot
fort <- fortify(nmds1)

#Generate 2 plots:
p1 <- ggplot(data = nmds_summary, mapping = aes(x = NMDS1_mean, y = NMDS2_mean, colour = Treatment, shape = Treatment)) +
#Customizes samples & plot error bars
  geom_errorbar(mapping = aes(xmin = NMDS1_mean - NMDS1_se, xmax = NMDS1_mean + NMDS1_se), width = 0.05, colour = "black", size = 1) +
  geom_errorbar(mapping = aes(ymin = NMDS2_mean - NMDS2_se, ymax = NMDS2_mean + NMDS2_se), width = 0.14383561643835616438356164383562, colour = "black", size = 1) +
  geom_point(size = 6, alpha = 1) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#C77CFF", "#00BFC4", "#F8766D", "#7CAE00")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16, 16, 15, 17)) +
#Set axis range and force rendering of objects "outside" the range
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.4, 0.4), xlim = c(-1.15, 1.15), clip = 'off') +
#Remove legend
  theme(legend.position="none") +
#Add custom legend
  annotate("text", x = 1.1, y = 0.365, size = 4, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "#C77CFF",
           label = ("Control start")) +
  annotate("text", x = 1.1, y = 0.34, size = 4, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "#00BFC4",
           label = ("Control end")) +
  annotate("text", x = 1.1, y = 0.315, size = 4, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "#F8766D",
           label = ("1% substrate addition")) +
  annotate("text", x = 1.1, y = 0.29, size = 4, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "#7CAE00",
           label = ("4% substrate addition")) +
#Generates coordinate system axis at the origin
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 0, linetype = "dotted", linewidth = 0.65, colour = "black") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0), linetype = "dotted", linewidth = 0.7125, colour = "black") +
#Removes grids & background & adds a frame
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = "NA", linewidth = 1, linetype = "solid")) +
#Add title as label so it is in the foreground
  annotate("label", x = -1.15, y = 0.36, size = 5.5, label.size = 0, fontface = "bold", hjust = 0, colour = "black",
           label = ("(a) Slump Floor (SF)")) +
#Add custom axis titles
  xlab("NMDS1") + ylab("NMDS2") +
#Customize left plot axis
  theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(-3, "mm"),
        axis.ticks = element_line(linewidth = 1.05),
        axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold", vjust = -0.6),
        axis.title.y.left = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold", vjust = 10),
#Set custom margin for better scale readability           
        plot.margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 35)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = c(-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1), labels = c("", "", "","",""), sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ., breaks = c(-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1), labels = c("", "", "","",""))) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = c(-0.2, 0 , 0.2), labels = c("", "",""), sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ., breaks = c(-0.2, 0 , 0.2), labels = c("", "",""))) +
#Set custom x-axis labels
  annotate("text", x = -0.95, y = -0.425, size = 4.5, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "black",
           label = ("-1")) +
  annotate("text", x = -0.43, y = -0.425, size = 4.5, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "black",
           label = ("-0.5")) +
  annotate("text", x = 0.025, y = -0.425, size = 4.5, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "black",
           label = ("0")) +
  annotate("text", x = 0.57, y = -0.425, size = 4.5, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "black",
           label = ("0.5")) +
  annotate("text", x = 1.025, y = -0.425, size = 4.5, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "black",
           label = ("1")) +
#Set custom y-axis labels  
  annotate("text", x = -1.2, y = 0.4, size = 4.5, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "black",
           label = ("0.4")) +
  annotate("text", x = -1.2, y = 0.205, size = 4.5, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "black",
           label = ("0.2")) +
  annotate("text", x = -1.2, y = 0, size = 4.5, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "black",
           label = ("0")) +
  annotate("text", x = -1.2, y = -0.195, size = 4.5, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "black",
           label = ("-0.2")) +
  annotate("text", x = -1.2, y = -0.395, size = 4.5, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "black",
           label = ("-0.4"))

p2 <- ggplot() +
#Add custom x-axis label
  geom_point(data = subset(fort, score == 'species'),
             mapping = aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2), alpha = 0) +
#Set axis range and force rendering of objects "outside" the range
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.4, 0.4), xlim = c(-1.15, 1.15), clip = 'off') +
  geom_segment(data = subset(fort, score == 'species'),
#Adds & customizes vectors for PLFAs
               mapping = aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = NMDS1, yend = NMDS2),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0, "npc"), type = "closed"),
               colour = "black", size = 0.8, alpha = 1)+
#Enable custom label colours and set to bold text
  geom_text_repel(data = subset(fort, score == 'species'),
                  mapping = aes(label = label, colour = label, x = NMDS1 * 1.025, y = NMDS2 * 1.025),
                  alpha = 1, size = 3, fontface = "bold") +
#Remove legend
  theme(legend.position="none") +
#Add custom legend
  annotate("text", x = 1.1, y = 0.365, size = 4, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "black",
           label = ("Non-specific")) +
  annotate("text", x = 1.1, y = 0.34, size = 4, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "#ff0000",
           label = ("Gram-positive bacteria")) +
  annotate("text", x = 1.1, y = 0.315, size = 4, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "#ff8800",
           label = ("Gram-negative bacteria")) +
  annotate("text", x = 1.1, y = 0.29, size = 4, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "#00b300",
           label = ("Fungi")) +
#Customize label colours
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("i15:0" = "#ff0000", "a15:0" = "#ff0000", "i16:0" = "#ff0000", "16:1ω7c" = "#ff8800", "16:1ω7t" = "#ff8800", "16:1ω5c" = "#ff8800", "16:0" = "black", "10Me 16:0" = "#ff0000", "i17:0" = "#ff0000", "a17:0" = "#ff0000", "17:1ω7c" = "#ff8800", "cy17:0" = "#ff8800", "17:0" = "black", "10Me 17:0" = "#ff0000", "18:2ω6c" = "#00b300", "18:1ω7c" = "#ff8800",  "18:1ω7t" = "#ff8800", "18:0" = "black", "10Me 18:0" = "#ff0000",  "cy19:0" = "#ff8800", "20:0" = "black")) +
#Generates coordinate system axis at the origin
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 0, linetype = "dotted", linewidth = 0.65, colour = "black") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0), linetype = "dotted", linewidth = 0.7125, colour = "black") +
#Removes grids & background & adds a frame
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = "NA", linewidth = 1, linetype = "solid")) +
#Add title below grid customization so it is in the foreground
  annotate("label", x = -1.15, y = 0.36, size = 5.5, label.size = 0, fontface = "bold", hjust = 0, colour = "black",
           label = ("(b) Slump Floor (SF)")) +
#Customize right plot axis
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(-3, "mm"),
        axis.ticks = element_line(linewidth = 1.05),
        axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold", vjust = -0.6),
#Set custom margin for better scale readability        
        plot.margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 10)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = c(-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1), labels = c("", "", "","",""), sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ., breaks = c(-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1), labels = c("", "", "","",""))) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = c(-0.2, 0 , 0.2), labels = c("", "",""), sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ., breaks = c(-0.2, 0 , 0.2), labels = c("", "",""))) +
#Set custom x-axis labels
  annotate("text", x = -0.95, y = -0.425, size = 4.5, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "black",
           label = ("-1")) +
  annotate("text", x = -0.43, y = -0.425, size = 4.5, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "black",
           label = ("-0.5")) +
  annotate("text", x = 0.025, y = -0.425, size = 4.5, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "black",
           label = ("0")) +
  annotate("text", x = 0.57, y = -0.425, size = 4.5, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "black",
           label = ("0.5")) +
  annotate("text", x = 1.025, y = -0.425, size = 4.5, fontface = "bold", hjust = 1, colour = "black",
           label = ("1"))

#Generate multi-panel plot with 2 columns & add/customize labels
ggarrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2, nrow = 1, widths = c(1.06, 1), align = "h")


JariO's approach:
library(vegan)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggvegan)
library(ggrepel)
library(ggpubr)
#Load data
data <- read.csv2("comSFdata.csv", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
#Create new dataframe w/o 1. column
com = data[,2:ncol(data)]
#Turn data from dataframe to matrix format
mcom = as.matrix(com)
#Run NMDS - set.seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)
nmds1 <- metaMDS(mcom, distance = "bray", k = 2, trymax = 10000)
#Prepare data for plotting
fort <- fortify(nmds1)
#Add workaround for adding back Treatment groups
fort['Treatment'] <- wa['Treatment']
#Remove rows without Treatment info
newfort <- na.omit(fort)

label <- c("#C77CFF","#C77CFF","#C77CFF","#C77CFF","#00BFC4","#00BFC4","#00BFC4","#00BFC4","#F8766D","#F8766D","#F8766D","#F8766D","#7CAE00","#7CAE00","#7CAE00","#7CAE00")
label2 <- c("#C77CFF","#00BFC4","#F8766D","#7CAE00")

#Ordibar
ordiplot(nmds1, display = "sites", type = "none", main = "Ordibar NMDS")
ordibar(nmds1, display = "sites", groups = data$Treatment, col = label2, length = 0.2)
points(newfort[, 3], newfort[, 4], pch = 16, cex = 1.5, col = label)
ordiellipse(nmds1, groups = data$Treatment, draw = "lines", col = label2, alpha = 1)


